# "No such DSL method '$' found among steps" error in groovy pipeline script

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

My very first pipeline script is throwing error as below:

```
Also:   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps [ <big text here>]
```

It triggered both the downstream_1 and downstream_2 jobs as expected, but finally failed with above error, here is the groovy script I have, any help/pointers to fix this?

```
pipeline {
agent
{
    node {
            label 'my_server'
          }
}

stages 
{
    stage('Start') {
        steps {
            sh 'ls'
        }
    }

    stage('End') {
        steps {
            script {
            def jobsString = "downstream_1,downstream_2"
            ArrayList jobsList = jobsString.split('\\,')

            def parallelJobs2Run = [:]
            jobsList.each { job ->
                echo "Run parallel for job ${job}"
                parallelJobs2Run["${job}"] = { ->
                    echo "Calling job ${job}"
                    jobResults=build job: "${job}",
                    parameters: [
                        string(name: 'param1', value: "value1"),
                        string(name: 'param2', value: "value2")
                    ],
                    propagate: true,
                    wait: true
                    buildNumber = ${jobResults.number}
                    echo "${job} Build number |${buildNumber}| result: |${jobResults.result}|"
                    echo "See details on: |${jobResults.absoluteUrl}|"
                }
            };
            parallel parallelJobs2Run
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This "big text" is the .toString from the job object. I'd assume, that it's either `build job: job` or `build job: job.name` (or whatever jenkins uses to know about a job). Anyways please add at least some of the omitted text so it's clear what was printed there.

Comment: the line `buildNumber = ${jobResults.number}` wont compile

Comment: @injecteer, yes, that was the one, can you please make it as answer and suggest how I get the buildNumber? thank you.

Answer (score 5):

this line

```
buildNumber = ${jobResults.number}
```

should be either

```
buildNumber = jobResults.number
```

or

```
buildNumber = "${jobResults.number}"
```